# imgly-sdk-ios SDK compilation in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8-beta6

How to resolve [compilation errors](https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-ios)  after upgrading to Xcode 8?

Comment: What type of errors do you get ... Roughly we can't assume the error which you get. Check if any files are missing while you compile